# Azure blob storage - using a SAS url for a blob file with ajax request returns 400

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I'm using a (working) SAS url to retrieve a file from azure blob storage using AJAX. I've enabled CORS in my Azure storage account and now I'm getting a 400 error:

Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.

The url works if I just paste it into a browser's address bar.